# How to set tblproperties of hive table using hive-site.xml or how to create all table as transaction table by setting properties in hive-site.xml

Tags: hive, tbl-properties

I want to create HIVE table with the transactional table with `TBLPROPERTIES ("transactional"="true")` `set using create table statement`. instead of setting for all tables can I set TBLPROPERTIES using hive-site.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we can't set it in hive-site.xml since `transactional` is a per table property. And we should not do it that way beacause 'transactional table' comes with some prerequisites and [limitations](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions#HiveTransactions-Limitations).